# UITableView separator does not appear correctly in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, separator

I'm a beginner in iOS developement and I try to make an e-catalogue.
I use a custom splitView to display the products list and in the masterView's the separator of my tableView does not appear correctly…

[image: pic' of the problem]

I already tried to solve the problem by setting the separator inset to 0 but it didn't work.

Have you an idea of what I'm supposed to do ?

[EDIT]

Currently I use the solution of putting a CALayer at the bottom of my cell (the code below is write in "CellForRowAtIndexPath"

```
CALayer *produitsCategorieCellBottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
produitsCategorieCellBottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(15, cell.frame.size.height-1, 320, 1.0f);
produitsCategorieCellBottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:198/255.0 green:197/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[cell.layer addSublayer:produitsCategorieCellBottomBorder];
```

If you find a better solution tell me PLEASE :)

[EDIT]

Comment: Where do you set the separator inset?

Comment: do you have your own content view ? Seems to be that separator is hidden

Comment: I tried to set the inset in storyBoard (it didn't work) and in the viewDidLoad of the view which contains the tableView (didn't work either)

yeah, I have my own Header view and define a custom cell with the prototype cell of my tableView

Comment: try with adding a UIView of height 1 in the header and the footer of the UITableview.

Comment: why you don't use standard tableview separator?

Comment: if you look at the pic, you'll see that if I use the standard separator there's a problem if the cell is not empty

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the custom views you are adding to the cell are overlapping the separator. Check their frames, and set the label backgrounds to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: I did what you said, and on simulator my labels and image didn't overlap the separator